# are there any Validation Controls in WPF controls just like Validation Controls in ASP.net

Tags: wpf, validation, controls

I've created a simple form in WPF. I have worked on ASP.NET previously, so I'm wondering if there are 'Validation Controls' in WPF that are similar to ASP.NET, or if I need to manually validate my fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can easily do this.  What you want is IDataErrorInfo interface.
 [here](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Binding, here's a [good post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903047/wpf-binding-use-dataannotations-for-validationrules)

Quickly, you want something like that :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

And then with `DataAnnotations` you specify your rules. Then you use the

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
```

function to validate. I use that all accross my application.