# validation in MVVM by using annotaions?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am new to WPF I need to validate those properties mentioned in my ViewModel how could I do it in a simplest way?
can anybody help? any way I can do it in MVVM.
I do have tried with the XAML template but there also I couldn't make it with multiple controls.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using FeedbackForm.Model;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
    namespace FeedbackForm.ViewModel
    {
        class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            static int i = 1;
            public data domObject;
            public ICommand _SubmitCmd{get;set;}
            public ICommand _ResetCmd{get;set;}
            public Connection con;


            public MainViewModel()
            {             
                 domObject= new data();
                _SubmitCmd = new DelegateComand.DelegateCommand(OnSubmit);            
                _ResetCmd = new DelegateComand.DelegateCommand(OnReset);
            }


            public class EmailValidationAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
            {
                public EmailValidationAttribute()
                    : base(@"^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-zA-Z0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1})|[a-zA-Z])\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$")
                {

                }
            }

            public string Fname
            {
                get 
                {return domObject.fname ;}
                set 
                {
                    domObject.fname =value ;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Fname");

                }
            }

            public string Lname
            {
                get
                { return domObject.lname; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.lname = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Lname");
                }
            }
            public bool Gender
            {
                get
                { return domObject.gender; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.gender = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
                }
            }

            public decimal Contact
            {
                get
                { return domObject.contact ; }
                set
                {

                    domObject.contact  = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged("Contact");
                 //   try
                 //   {
                 //       //int.Parse(Contact);
                 //       Convert.ToInt32(Contact);
                 //  }
                 //  catch (Exception ex)
                 //{
                 //    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Number");
                 //}
                }
            }
    [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Not in proper format")]
            public string Email
            {
                get
                { return domObject.email; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.email = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Email");

            }
           }

            public string Address
            {
                get
                { return domObject.address ; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.address  = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Address");
                }
            }

            public string Query
            {
                get
                { return domObject.query ; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.query  = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Query");
                }
            }

            public string Comment
            {
                get
                { return domObject.comment ; }
                set
                {
                    domObject.comment  = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Comment");
                }
            }

            private void OnReset(object obj)
            {
                ResetAll(this );
            }

            private void OnSubmit(object obj)
            {   char g;   
                con = new Connection();

                try{
                        if (domObject.gender == false)
                        {
                            g = 'M';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            g = 'F';
                        }
                        con.command.CommandText = "Insert into tblfeedback(fname,lname,gender,email,contact_no,Address) values('" + domObject.fname + "','" + domObject.lname + "','" + g + "','" + domObject.email + "','" + domObject.contact + "','" + domObject.address + "')";
                        con.command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.command.CommandText = "Insert into comment (query,comment,date)values('" + domObject.query + "','" + domObject.comment + "','" +( DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().ToString())+ "')";
                        con.command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        i++;
                        ResetAll(this);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
                }
            }

             public void ResetAll(object obj)
              {          
               Fname = String.Empty;
               Lname = String.Empty;
               Gender = false;
               Contact = 0;
               Address = String.Empty;
               Query = String.Empty;
               Comment = String.Empty;
               Email = String.Empty;       

              }






            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

            /// <summary>
            /// Event to which the view's controls will subscribe.
            /// This will enable them to refresh themselves when the binded property changes provided you fire this event.
            /// </summary>
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            /// <summary>
            /// When property is changed call this method to fire the PropertyChanged Event
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                //Fire the PropertyChanged event in case somebody subscribed to it
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }


Following Xaml contains the Template which I used to validate contact property but I want to validate my Email by any means. I am new to WPF so I just want to know how can I use Regular Expression or anything to do that???



    <Window x:Class="FeedbackForm.View.Window1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Window1" Height="490.602" Width="549.249">
        <Window.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
        Foreground="Red"
        FontSize="12pt" Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}">

                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
        <DockPanel Background="Aquamarine">
            <Grid Margin="0,25,0,-25">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="51*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="47*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="44*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="48*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="61*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="74*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="64*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="72*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="130"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="First Name" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="67"/>
                <Label Content="Gender" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,2,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="49"/>
                <Label Content="E-mail" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="43"/>
                <Label Content="Contact" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,5,0,0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="51"/>
                <Label Content="Address"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,4,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="53"/>
                <Label Content="Query"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,3,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="42"/>
                <Label Content="Comment"  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,3,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="62"/>
                <Label Content="Last Name" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="66"/>
                <Button x:Name="submit" Command="{Binding Path=_SubmitCmd}" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,10,0,0" Grid.Row="7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22" Grid.Column="1" Click="submit_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="reset" Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,10,0,0" Grid.Row="7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" Command="{Binding _ResetCmd}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtfname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Fname}" TabIndex="1"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtlname" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="262,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Column="1"  TabIndex="2">
                    <Binding Path="Lname"></Binding>
                </TextBox> 
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdfemale" Content="FEMALE" GroupName="grp1" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Width="82"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="rdmale" Content="MALE" GroupName="grp1"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Height="16" Width="82" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtemail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Grid.Column="1"   TabIndex="3">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Email" Mode="TwoWay">
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtcontact"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Grid.Column="1"  TabIndex="4">


                       <TextBox.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Contact" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                    <ExceptionValidationRule></ExceptionValidationRule>
                                </Binding.ValidationRules> 

                            </Binding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtxtquery" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="10,23,0,0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.413" Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="6" >
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Query}"/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtxtadd"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.413" Grid.Column="1" TabIndex="5">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>
                    <RichTextBox Grid.Column="1"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="276" TabIndex="7">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Comment}"/>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                    </RichTextBox>

                </Grid>

            </DockPanel>


        </Window>
```

Comment: please also show your XAML

Comment: and check [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903047/wpf-binding-use-dataannotations-for-validationrules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Validation Rule or Using IDataErrorInfo
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo