# Custom advanced entity validation with Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm looking for a solution to perform some custom entity validation (which would require database access, cross-member validation...) when the user saves its changes in a Dynamic Data screen, with Entity Framework.
The validation is more complex than what I can do with the attributes (it requires an access to the database, etc.)

Can you intercept the SaveChanges call ?
I tried to override `ValidateEntity` in the DbContext object, but Dynamic Data doesn't seem to call it (probably because it's using the internal ObjectContext, not sure why), and overriding SaveChanges doesn't help either.
I don't see any event that I could subscribe to...

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225428.aspx#Validating) should help :

> Customize validation for an individual data field by overriding the
>   OnValidate method or handling the Validate event, which are invoked
>   when any data field is changed. This approach lets you add validation
>   and business logic for an individual field. This approach is more
>   general than adding validation for an individual field. It is useful
>   when the same validation logic can be applied to more than one data
>   field. It also lets you perform validation checks that involve
>   multiple fields.

But I'm using POCO Entity Framework 6 classes so there's no `OnValidate` method to override, and from what I read this is for LinqToSql, and I can't find the `Validate` event they mention.

I tried to subscribe to the `SavingChanges` event of the inner `ObjectContext` in the constructor of my DbContext, to call manually the `ValidateEntity`, but I don't know what to do with the result. If I throw a `DbEntityValidationException` (or a `ValidationException` like suggested in [this article](http://xharze.blogspot.fr/2011/06/aspnet-dynamic-data-part-8-customizing.html)), ASPNET handle it like any exception (yellow screen).

Implementing `IValidatableObject` doesn't work either.

I also tried implementing my own `DynamicValidator` to see what happens, but with no success, it seems to handle the exception (if I override `ValidateException`, and put a breakpoint, I see it) but it's still bubbled up to the default error handler and displays a yellow screen. I must be missing something.

So, how should you perform complex validation (cross-field, with queries, etc.)  on entities before saving in Dynamic Data / EF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround I don't like, but it works :

My Context is still performing the validation and throws a `ValidationException` if necessary.

As the `ListView` doesn't seem to catch and handle the exception, I do it myself by handling the `OnItemUpdated` or `OnItemInserted` event of the `ListView` :

```
protected void ListView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        ValidationError.DisplayError(e.Exception.Message);
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        e.KeepInEditMode = true;
    }
}
```

`ValidationError` is used to add the exception message to the validation summary. It adds a "fake", always failing validator with the message.

```
public class ValidationError : BaseValidator
{
    private ValidationError(string message)
        : base()
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
        IsValid = false;
    }

    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static void DisplayError(string message, string validationGroup)
    {
        var currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        currentPage.Validators.Add(new ValidationError(message) { ValidationGroup = validationGroup });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that logic like you are trying to perform doesn't belong at such a level in your architecture. Let the database enforce the constraints it is supposed to, like foreign keys etc., and have your business logic a layer above. For example, on your entity you are wanting to validate you could add a `IsValidForAddOrUpdate()` method, which contains the logic you'd put in your validators anyway. Then just utilise the new methods:

```
if (entity.IsValidForAddOrUpdate())
{
    db.Set<Entity>().Add(entity);
    db.SaveChanges()
}
else throw new DbValidationException("Entity failed validation due to rule xyz.");
```

Comment: i agree with this statement, I also beleive that business logic should not be coupled with entity framework

Comment: It's arguable. Perhaps a domain layer object could have the validation instead. As long as the awful 'repository layer in front of EF' pattern isn't used...

Comment: I agree, but Dynamic Data doesn't give many options for validation. But the problem is not there, the problem is that DbValidationException is not caught by DynamicValidator (although the docs and articles I find say it should) so I get a yellow screen.
Right now I'm not even trying to have a good architecture, just to have something that works :(.

Answer (score 3):

One way how to achive this could be implementing `IDataErrorInfo` interface on your entities like this:

```
public partial class MyEntity : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
    }

    ...

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            //Custom Validation logic
            return  MyValidator.ValidateProperty(this, propertyName);
        }
    }
    #endregion  
}
```

To access current DBContext from IDataErrorInfo methods you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25231150/2224701).
Then override your Context's SaveChanges method:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

        // Get all the new and updated objects
        var objectsToValidate =
        ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Added).
        Select(e => e.Entity);

        // Check each object for errors
        foreach (var obj in objectsToValidate)
        {
            if (obj is IDataErrorInfo)
            {
                // Check each property
                foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var columnError = (obj as IDataErrorInfo)[property.Name];
                    if (columnError != null) {
                    //Handle your validation errors
                    throw new DbEntityValidationException(columnError); }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925767/2224701) to make it work with DataAnnotations.

You wrote:

> If I throw a DbEntityValidationException (or a ValidationException
>   like suggested in this article), ASPNET handle it like any exception
>   (yellow screen).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258174/2224701). When you call `SaveChanges` you need to catch `DbEntityValidationException` (or `ValidationException`), if you do not catch them to process them within your Controller, they are processed by the default error handler.

Or you can use [DynamicValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679100%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) control to catch ValidationExceptions:

```
    <!-- Capture validation exceptions -->
    <asp:DynamicValidator ID="ValidatorID" ControlToValidate="GridView1" 
        runat="server" />
```

The problem with `DynamicValidator` is that it requires `ControlToValidate` property and it catches only exceptions coming from that control. Also exceptions encapsulated within other exceptions can crate problems. There is a workaround - you can inherit from `DynamicValidator` and override its `ValidateException` method [see this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidebb/2008/12/11/handling-database-exceptions-in-dynamic-data/).

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488527.aspx).

Comment: Yes, exactly what I found, but the DynamicValidator doesn't catch the Exception, I don't know why. If I debug, I see that it steps into the ValidateException method and it seems to detect it and do things with it ( [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.DynamicData/DynamicData/DynamicValidator.cs,a9f61764351be893,references) ), but the Exception still goes up to the default error handler.
I even tried the ImprovedDynamicValidator from the Dynamic Data Futures package, but it doesn't work either.
I can't catch it in the Controller, as there are none with Dynamic Data.

Comment: I see, interesting problem, I will take a look on it on Thursday if it does not get answered meanwhile.